# Electron, Javascript: How to select an array within an array returned by the database

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, promise, electron

I want to foreach an array to show on the screen. This array is the data from a database table.

The code to get this data:

```
const { getConnection } = require('./database');

async function getUsers() {
   const conn = getConnection();
   var usuarios = (await conn).query('SELECT * FROM user');
   console.log(usuarios)
}
```

But this variable comes this way:

[image]

And I'm not able to select that array (_rejectionHandler0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `.query` also returns a `Promise`, you need to `await` it.

```
var usuarios = await (await conn).query('SELECT * FROM user');
```

`await conn` waits for the connection to be obtained and the outer `await` waits for the query to finish.

Alternatively, you can `await` each one separately:

```
const conn = await getConnection();
var usuarios = await conn.query('SELECT * FROM user');
```